# Screen pop opportunities

Tags: opportunity, cti, opencti

I am able to screen pop contact and cases using open CTI, but not able do with the opportunities. When I type in opportunities name in search box I am able see the search result, but no result when using open CTI JS searchAndScreenPop function.

Any one has done search based on opportunities please share your experience.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

Customize the Softphone layout and add the required objects, like opportunities/campaign/task. Then the search results will have the records for these objects.